# Cannot get the "save changes" button to be ungreyed once the jQuery datepicker is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom, datepicker

For some reason, my code seems to ignore the fact that when a date is selected using the jQuery date picker, it should re-enable my "save changes" button. If I change a value in any of the other input boxes it seems to work just fine. I can't seem to quite figure this out and wrap my head around the problem.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();


$('.check input').keyup(function() { $('#save').attr('disabled', false); });

$( "#save" ).click(function() { $('#save').attr('disabled', true); });


});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="check">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt1" value="text1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt2" value="text2"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt3" value="text3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt4" value="text4"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt5" value="text5"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt6" value="text6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt7" value="text7"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt8" value="text8"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="datepicker" />Date Picker</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<input id="save" type="button" value="save changes" disabled> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.onSelect` and [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

*the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve **property** values, while .attr() retrieves **attributes**.*

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function () {
        $('#save').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: When a date is picked, it still doesn't enable my save button.

Comment: @JasonKelly - great. glad to help. please upvote & accept as answer when you get a chance.